# Display Counter Number for Pre-Populated Input Field

Tags: javascript

I have a PHP page that pulls data from a database and auto-populates an input box. The code below is of a counter that displays how many characters are in a field upon typing.

However, when the PHP page is pulled up with the field populated, the counter says "0" until I type something in. How can I change the code so the counter displays how many characters are in the auto-populated field without me having to type something in? And then of course it should update when I do type something in.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function textCounter(field, countfield, maxlimit) {
  if (field.value.length > maxlimit) {
    field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
    countfield.value = 'max characters';
  // otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
  }else {
    countfield.value = field.value.length;
  }
}
</script>

<center>
<form name=myform action="#">
<font size="1" face="arial, helvetica, sans-serif"> 
( You may enter up to 125 characters. )<br>
<input type="text" name="message" id="message"
 onKeyDown="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);" 
 onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);"
    >
<br>
<input readonly type=text name=remLen size=3 maxlength=3 value="0"> characters total</font>
</form>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window.document.onload to call your textCounter function

something like

```
    <script>
    window.document.onload=function(){
        var form = document.getElementsByName('myform')[0];
        textCounter(form.message,form.remLen,125);
    };
    ....
```

Or just call your function on the onchange event like

```
<input type="text" name="message" id="message"
 onchange="textCounter(this.form.message,this.form.remLen,125);" >
```

Comment: Rajeev, thank you, but I tried adding that code to the JavaScript and no luck. came up with "0" still

Comment: At what point do you update the message with the value from the DB?

Comment: it's like a form. for example, click "edit" on user details and the user can edit their name, address, etc.

Comment: Since the above code is not working I can only guess that you are populating the 'message' after the document has loaded. In this case I would suggest calling the function on the onChange event. Let me update the answer further.